# Cabal build error sh: 'inappropriate type' ghc7.8.3 Cabal-1.22 OSX10.10 Yosemite

Tags: haskell, cabal

Cannot install network-2.6.0.2, and the log says it's an inappropriate type error.

`cabal install network`

```
setup-Configure-Cabal-1.22.0.0-x86_64-linux-ghc-7.8.3: sh: inappropriate type
```

Version Info: *GHC 7.8.3, Cabal 1.22, OSX 10.10*

My dotfile settings:

```
export GHC_HOME=/usr/local/bin/ghc
export CABAL_HOME=$HOME/.cabal/
```

Answer (score 1):

Double check your `$PATH` settings. Removing ghc at the end of GHC_HOME worked for me. Here's what I ended up with.

```
export GHC_HOME=/usr/local/bin
export CABAL_HOME=$HOME/.cabal/
export PATH=$GHC_HOME:$CABAL_HOME/bin:${PATH}
```

Note: you may have to explicitly write out the path for `$HOME`, i.e. `CABAL_HOME=/Users/yourname/.cabal/` In case you were wondering about quotes - they're only required if your directory has a space.

Reference: network [#146](https://github.com/haskell/network/issues/146), ghcjs [#143](https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs/issues/143#issuecomment-55239767)